# How to obtain gRPC status in a Async C++ Client

Tags: grpc-c++

I am implementing a gRPC Async client with C++, and I need to get the grpc-status returned by the server to error treatment, but the AsyncNext API only returns the NextStatus with is associate to the CompletionQueue which doesn't contain the status returned by Server but the status for the completion queue.

How is it possible to obtain the grpc status returned by the server? I have tried associate a Interceptor object to the channel, but I can't see any call with hook points for Receive status.  I expect that POST_RECV_STATUS or PRE_RECV_STATUS hook point should be called when a status message was received by the channel, don't I?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncNext also returns `&event_tag`.
this tag you should put in your async operations: Read, Write, Finish.

it's your tag, and it serves for identification gRPC context.
you could create TagContext Map for this.
and pick up updated context associated with returned tag after operation on AsyncNext loop event.